# Jest mockImplementationOnce not overriding manual mock

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I have a manual mock inside the `__mocks__` folder, called `client.ts`.  Now in my unit test I call `jest.mock('./client')`. This works fine and jest imports the mocked folder. Now I have one scenario (test) where I need to override this behavior. I used `mockImplementationOnce` in the unit test.

```
import mockClient from './client';
(mockClient.getObject as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  console.log('calling the mock of the mock');
  return Promise.resolve('abcde');
});
```

Now when I run this test, Jest still seems to load the manual mock inside the `__mocks__` folder instead of loading this mock for this particular test. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import mockClient from './client';

test('getObject', async () => {
   mockClient.getObject.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
     console.log('calling the mock of the mock');
     return Promise.resolve('abcde');
   });

   await mockClient.getObject();
})
```

I consider a good practice to use `mockImplementationOnce` just before the call, to avoid any overriding in the `beforeEach` or any other conflict.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from the code I gave above apart from the syntax difference.  Plus no another note if I'm importing an object which is in turn dependant on another object being mocked, should I re-import the original object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Did you try the sintax I proposed and it didn't work? Did you put the `mockImplementationOnce` just before the call like I suggested?